# modal problem partial view same data show but different item selected

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

> Hi Everyone, I try to used the modal to avoid having multiple pages. but I got a problem, first, I click the view button and it will display to modal the right information; but when I click other view button instead the next data, it display the previous data.
> second, after I select the view button and try to select the new shoes button (expectation must be display the new module in modal) it display the data of the previous item I select in view button:

```
    Controller:
    
          public ActionResult Index() //main page
                {
                    var result = _Context.Shoeses.Include(x => x.Supply).ToList();
                    return View(result);
                }
     
    
         public ActionResult New() //create new product
                {
                    var SupplierCategory = _Context.Suppliers.ToList();
                    var listOfSupplier = new ShoesViewModel
                    {
                        Supply = SupplierCategory
                    };
                    return PartialView(listOfSupplier);
                }
    
         public ActionResult Details(int id) //view selected data
                {
                    Shoes productItem = new Shoes();
                    productItem = _Context.Shoeses.Find(id);
                    return PartialView("_Details", productItem);
                }
    
    View: Index
    
            @model  IEnumerable<ShoeInformation.Models.Shoes>
            @{
                ViewBag.Title = "Index";
                Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
            }
            
            <br />
            <br />
            <h2>Tindahan sa Bahay ni Tatang Benjamin</h2>
            <br />
            <br />
        //my modal
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                            <h3 class="modal-title">Details</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
                            Testing Only
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        //my modal
              <p>@Html.ActionLink("New Shoes", "New", "Shoes", new { id="btn_Modal"}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg",@data_toggle="modal" ,@data_target="#myModal"})</p>
                
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product ID
                    </th>
                    <th>Product Code
                    </th>
                    <th>Product Name
                    </th>
                    <th>Item Size
                    </th>
                    <th>Supplier
                    </th>
                    <th>Available Quantity
                    </th>
                    <th>Unit Price (Php)
                    </th>
                    <th>Action
                    </th>
                </tr>
            
          

  @foreach (var shoes in Model)
            { 
                <tr class="success">
                    <td>
                        @shoes.Id
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @shoes.ProductCode
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      @Html.ActionLink(@shoes.ProductName, "Edit", "Shoes", new { id=shoes.Id})
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @shoes.ItemSize
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" value="@shoes.Id" id="hiddenval" />
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => shoes.Id)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => shoes.Supply.SupplierName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @shoes.ItemQty
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @shoes.ItemUnitPrice
                    </td>
        
                    <td>
                       
         @Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", "Shoes", new { id=shoes.Id}, new { @class = "view-Modal",@data_toggle="modal" ,@data_target="#myModal"})
        
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        
        
        </table>
        @*<a href="#" id="btn_Modal" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal Testing</a>*@
        
        
        @section scripts
        {
            <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function()
                {
                    $('#myModal').hide();

                    $("#btn_Modal").click(function () {
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    });

                    $(".view-Modal").click(function () {
                        var productId = 
$(this).closest('tr').find('#hiddenval').val();
                            
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '/Shoes/Details',
                                data: { id: productId },
                                success: function (response)
                                {
                                    $('#modalBody').html(response);
                                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                                }
                            });
                        })
            
                        $(".close").click(function ()
                        {
                            console.log("Clear All");
                        });
            
                      
                    });
                </script>
            }

partial view: _details
@model  ShoeInformation.Models.Shoes

    <div>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="tablemodel">
            
                    <tr>
                         <tr>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Id)
                         </tr>
                        <tr>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.ProductName)
                        </tr>
              
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> I try to breakpoint to see the problem but everything is working properly,  however in the modal it display the same value
>
> can someone please help me regarding to this matter
> thanks in advance